# OpenAccess ORM - WithCascadeDelete Not Available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik-open-access, openaccess

I am using ORM version 2013.2.702.1 and ASP.NET MVC 4.5. I am trying to use WithCascadeDelete like the documentation: [Cascade Delete on Class Level](http://documentation.telerik.com/openaccess-orm/documentation/developers-guide/code-only-mapping/inheritance/fluent-mapping-inheritance-vertical-cascade-delete#cascade_delete_on_class_level), but the method is not available:

```
using FluentModel.Entity;
using Telerik.OpenAccess.Metadata;
using Telerik.OpenAccess.Metadata.Fluent;

namespace FluentModel.Map
{
public class ProdutoMap
{
    public static MappingConfiguration<Produto> CreateConfiguration()
    {
        var produtoMapping = new MappingConfiguration<Produto>();

        produtoMapping.MapType(p => new
        {
            p.Id,
            p.Nome,
            p.Preco,
            p.Descricao,
            p.DataCadastro

        }).ToTable("produto");

        produtoMapping.HasProperty(p => p.Id).IsIdentity(KeyGenerator.Autoinc);
        produtoMapping.HasProperty(p => p.Nome).HasLength(60);
        produtoMapping.HasProperty(p => p.Preco).IsCurrency();
        produtoMapping.HasProperty(p => p.Descricao).HasLength(60);

        produtoMapping.HasAssociation(p => p.Categoria)
                   .WithOpposite(c => c.Produtos)
                   .HasConstraint((p, c) => p.CategoriaId == c.Id)
                   .ToColumn("Categoria_id");


        return produtoMapping;
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to use:

```
produtoMapping.MapType().WithCascadeDelete()
```

The compiler cannot resolve the method.

Any Idea why?

Comment: I am afraid there is not a release of the product with this method yet. It should be available in the next internal build.

Comment: Damyan, thanks for your help, maybe you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, OpenAccess ORM has a Q3 2013 Beta version that includes the Cascade Delete feature. You can download it from [here](http://www.telerik.com/account/your-products/product-versions.aspx?pmvid=3385&pid=639) once you log in your account.

Let me just add that the Cascade Delete feature is available only **for models that utilize Verticle Inheritance and [Multi-Table Entities](http://documentation.telerik.com/openaccess-orm/developers-guide/code-only-mapping/mapping-clr-types-properties-and-associations/advanced-mapping/multi-table-entities/fluent-mapping-mapping-clr-advanced-multi-table-entities-cascade-delete)**.